# MySQL table organization and optimization (Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization

I've been learning Ruby on Rails over the past few months with no prior programming experience.  Lately, I've been thinking about database optimization and table organization.  I know there are great books on the subject, but I typically learn by example / as I go.

Here's a hypothetical situation:

Let's say I am building a social network for a niche community with 250,000 members (users).  The users have the ability to attend events.  Let's say there are 50,000 past/present/future events.  Much like Facebook events, a user can attend any number of events and an event can have any number of attendees.

In the database, there would be a table for users and a table for events.  Somehow I would have to create an association between the users and events.  I could create an "events" column in the users table such that each user row would contain a hash of event IDs, or I could create an "attendees" column in the events table such that each event row would contain a hash of user IDs.

Neither of these solutions seem ideal, however.  On a user's profile page, I want to display the list of events they are associated with, which would require scanning the 50,000 event rows for the user ID of said user if I include an "attendees" column in the events table.  Likewise, on an event page, I want to display a list of attendees for the event, which would require scanning the 250,000 user rows for the event ID of said event if I include an "events" column in the users table.

Option 3 would be to create a third table that contains the attendee information for each and every event - but I don't see how this would solve any problems.

Are these non-issues?  Rails makes accessing all of this information easy, but I guess I'm worried about scale.  It is entirely possible that I am under-estimating the speed and processing power of modern databases / servers / etc.  How long would it take to scan 250,000 user rows for specific event IDs - 10ms? 100ms?  1,000ms?  I guess that's not that bad.  Am I just over-thinking this?

Comment: With proper indexes, a query can handle 50 million of records in a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical many-to-many relationship between users and events.

You need a third table (say UserEvent or better **UserAttendsEvent** or just Attends) which will have a row for every user and every event the user attends.

So it will have at least a userID and an eventID, both as foreign keys to the User and Event table.

Adding indexes on these 2 fields will probably be good for your queries, since you plan to have millions of rows.

The UserEvent may also have other data, like when a user registered for an event, money she spent on the event, if she enjoyed it or not, etc.

The catch is that every row has information regarding "Attends". Who attended (userID), what attended (eventID), when he arrived, amount spent during, etc. You don't want to put this info in neither the User table nor the Event table.

Since you are worried about performance, I'll add an example of how the database would search for a specific query. Lets say we want to find all users that attend (or plan to) event "U2 concert in Athens, July 2011" and have same birthday as me.

```
database plan:
1. use eventTitle index in table Event 
     to find that the event has id 47519 
   (good for us that we have created such an index).
2. use eventID index in table Attends 
     to find all (469) userids that have attended eventid 47519.
3. use the userid index in table User
     to find all the info of the 469 users.
4. search the info (birthdate) from those
     to keep only those (3) that have birthday July 24th.
     (we have not created any index that can be used here)
```

So, the database access the disks only to search indexes and read the data we need. Not to read all data and search in them.

In more complex queries or because the query requires all data in a table or if an index needed hasn't been created or some index is not useful or if db query optimizer decides it's faster, it may scan a table or part of it and then search for the data. But  if "*proper*" indexes have been defined (proper for you planned use), the queries will be fast.

Comment: Just to clarify - a single row would contain one user ID and one event ID?  So if a 3 users each attend 5 events, there would be 15 rows in the UserEvent table?

Comment: Exactly. This is a very common practise.

Answer (score 0):

"On a users profile page, I want to display the list of events they are associated with, which would require scanning the 50,000 event rows for the user ID of said user if I include an "attendees" column in the events table."

It would have to scan the 50,000 event rows if each user ID were not a unique key, which I certainly hope it is. If each user ID is unique key, then it's quick. Likewise the events table: each event would have a unique ID which is also its unique key.

You have to make those IDs be unique keys, otherwise you're in deep sneakers.

-- Pete

Comment: Yes, there would be a unique ID for each user and a unique ID for each event.  Rails does this by convention - right?  I thought that part of it was assumed, I just have no idea how long these kind of db queries would take.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but adding detail whilst I'm looking for other things.

In Rails, this is handled through the "has_and_belongs_to_many" clause in the model, which creates the many-to-many resolution table for you.  Documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

With a resolution entity, the database doesn't actually scan the entire table looking for the information, it uses a b-tree index to find the specific rows that are needed - hence a many-to--many does directly fix the performance problem you're raising.